# Offline Electron install, stop @electron/get calling GitHub?

Tags: angular, electron

## The Problem

As a project for work I have been creating test applications in a number of monorepo cross platform frameworks. I'm trialling Angular for use on the web, Android and Windows. I've got a Ionic project working as a web app and the next step is to run it as a desktop app. But I've failed to install Electron.

Our development environment is the major restriction, as it's a Windows VM with no access to the Internet.  We host dependencies through Artifactory and have had no issues using npm to set up the example web project.

This is the installation log when Electron is trying to call GitHub for the latest dependencies.

```
npm info run electron@28.2.2 postinstall node_modules/electron node install.js
npm info run electron@28.2.2 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
npm verb stack Error: command failed
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UKX0800\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:53:27)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm verb pkgid electron@28.2.2
npm verb cwd D:\repo\angular\ionic-test
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm verb node v20.11.0
npm verb npm  v10.2.1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\repo\angular\ionic-test\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 20.27.177.113:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\repo\angular\ionic-test\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:530:35)
npm ERR!     at origin.emit (D:\repo\angular\ionic-test\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)
npm verb exit 1
```

## What I've Tried

Following advice from Electron's [advanced installation guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#custom-mirrors-and-caches) and this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543176/how-to-install-electron-offline-without-github) I have set up a mirror hosted locally on the development VM.

It's using http-server from npm and when tested through chrome downloads the binaries correctly, seen in pic below. As far as I can tell I have also set the correct environment variables, also see below. But I get the same error message as above with no indication that Electron has tried anything different during post install?

[http-server console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGw5X.png)

```
ELECTRON_MIRROR=http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ELECTRON_CUSTOM_DIR=v28.2.2
ELECTRON_CUSTOM_FILENAME=electron-v28.2.2-win32-x64.zip
```

I've also tried to install electron on a machine that does have access to the Internet and then add it manually to the cache on a dev machine. But it seems that I can't get out to https://registry.npmjs.org/electron on the company's internet as I get a ETIMEDOUT error. I can't really recommend a framework that requires us to download the dependencies at home and bring them in on a memory stick!

Is there something that I'm missing, or is it not possible to install Electron like this?